# how to split an integer and add everything to an array?

Tags: c++

there is a number like

```
int a = 12345;
```

I need to do it separately

```
int arr[4]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

But the fact is, I don’t know what the number will be
it can be long or short.

Comment: Simplest would be using a `std::vector`, push_back the remainder of 10 again and again and then reverse the vector. Assuming 32 bit int, you might `vector.reserve(11)` before, as this would be the maximum number of digits that can occur. Do you need to consider negative input, too?

Comment: By the way, you have one digit too few in your array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number to a string, then fill a vector by looping over each individual character.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int a = 12345;
std::string stringInt = std::to_string(a);

std::vector<int> numbers;
numbers.reserve(stringInt.length());

for(const auto& chr : stringInt)
{
  numbers.push_back(chr - '0');
}
```

This doesn't deal with edge-cases or error-handling, that's for you to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Think about what happens when you divide a number by 10.

What is 12345 divided by 10? It is 1234. How much is the remainder of that division? It is 5. You've now  split the least significant digit from the rest. How might you get the next digit? Keep in mind that you already have 1234. Well, you repeat the division by 10 and now you have 123 and 4. Repeat until you no longer have digits. There's the algorithm that you're looking for.

This works with 10 because that is the radix (i.e. base) of the decimal representation. The same algorithm works with other representations by using the radix in question. This algorithm demonstrates how dividing by radix corresponds to "shifting" digits right (multiplication shifts left) and remainder operation "masks" away all digits except least significant one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same way as converting an integer to string i.e.

```
std::vector<int> split;
int integer = 12345;
while( 0 != integer) {
  split.push_back( integer % 10 );
  integer /= 10;
}
std::reverse(split.begin(), split.end());
```

Comment: You might yet want to `split.reserve(10)` (32-bit int provided) or ideally [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) to avoid re-allocations.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code.

```
// num is input number
void split(long long  num)
{
    int i;
     vector<long long>  ve;
     ve.clear();
     while(num>0){
        long long rem=num%10;
        ve.pb(rem);
        num/=10;
     }
     //for output array
   reverse(ve.begin(),ve.end());
     for(i=0;i<ve.size();i++)
        cout<<ve[i]<<endl;


}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `ve.pb` -> `ve.push_back`. Also why are you declaring `int i` at the top, when you can do it in the `for` statement and why are you `clear`ing an empty `vector`?

Comment: There's no need to store digits in `long long` vector, range will be [-9..9] anyway, so int is sufficient (be aware that long long can be larger than system's memory bus, so you might need more than one operation to store the value). There's no need to `clear()` an entirely new vector, it is created empty anyway. Instead, it would be meaningful to `ve.reserve(19)` to avoid re-allocations, or better, [`std::numeric_limits<long long>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) (theoretically, at least, long long might be larger than 64 bits).